# change format of get date function

Tags: sql-server

When using this statement

```
select urn,GETDATE() from table1 where urn not in(select urn from table2)
```

the format of the date is Oct 10 2012  1:57PM. However I want it to be in this format 20121010

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

Use [CONVERT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function in sql server

```
select CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112)
```

## [SQl fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5123)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]
```

select urn, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) as  [YYYYMMDD] 
  from table1 where urn not in(select urn from table2)

```
and also refer more format :
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx
```